# false position method in matlab

Tags: matlab, root

Can someone help me check where did I get wrong in the following code?

It is using False Position Method to find out the root of a function. Thanks

```
clc
clear all
format compact

x0=-2; x1=2; tol=10^-6; n=100;
f=@(x)x^3*5*x.^2+3*x-9;
y0=f(x0); 
y1=f(x1);

i=1;
while i<=n
    x=x1-y1*(x1-x0)/(y1-y0);
    if abs(x-x1)<tol
        disp('Root of function:');
        disp(x);
        break
    end

    i=i+1;
    y=x^3*5*x.^2+3*x-9;

    if y0*y1<0
        x0=x;
        y0=y;
    else 
        x1=x;
        y1=y;
    end
end
```

Comment: Your `if` condition should be `abs(f(x))<tol` instead of comparing the initial guess and final solution values. I think it is self-explanatory. Also, you should compare `y*y1` instead of `y0*y1`. Though I still don't think my solution can tackle all the situations that is why I am not posting it as an answer.

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: no, still nothing displayed.

Comment: Hopefully this problem is already solved. Problems in the code: in the definition of `f(x)`, you use `x.^2` but then also `x^3`, that should be consistent. And I'm almost sure that your function is `x.^3+5*x.^2+3*x-9` or `x.^3-5*x.^2+3*x-9`. In the loop itself you should use `f(x)`, but actually you have there a copy of the formula.

Comment: Regula falsi does not guarantee that the interval shrinks to a point. For that use the Illinois variant. To get a finite iteration with the current code, change the condition to `abs(x-x0)<tol OR abs(x-x1)<tol`. Break the loop and return also if `y` is small enough `abs(y)<tol`. This can be made scale-independent by using the initial y0, y1 values as in `scale_y=1e-8  +max(abs(y0),abs(y1))` and compare `abs(y)<tol*scale_y`.